# What is the Language described by this NFA?

Tags: regex, regular-language, automata, finite-automata

[image]

Using set builder notation, what is the Language described by this NFA?
At first I thought it would be

L = { 1^n (01)^m 1^o | n,m,o >= 0} But then the string 101111101, which is accepted by this NFA is not accepted by the language I just described.

Comment: Does the syntax allow "OR"?

Comment: perhaps it's more like `(1*(01)*)*`

Comment: If the notation includes the star operation then you should use that.

Comment: I doubt it includes the Kleene star, but for a regular expression it should be valid...

Comment: We cannot use kleene star or U or intersection.

Comment: I'm guessing you can do something like this, I'm not too sure about set builder notation though, `L = { (1^n(01)^m)^o | n,m,o >= 0}`

Comment: For the string 101111101, what would n, m and o be? n,m,and o do not act like kleene stars do they? But that is how we should write it (the notation)

Comment: @LilithX I'm guessing n and m can change for each `o`, so 1(01) (n=1, m=1), then next iteration of `o`, should be 11111(01) (n=5, m=1). So `o=2` but n and m can change for each o. I'm not sure if the syntax I wrote in the above comment actually means this though as I'm not really familiar with set notation. You might get better answers [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) or [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's important to allow varying numbers of 1's between zeros. All those exponents need to be independent. `{ (1^n_i 0 1)^k 1^m, n_i >= 0 | k>=0, n_i >=0, i=1..k, m>=0 }`

Comment: @Gene What do you mean by n_i and i=1..k ?

Comment: @LilithX There are k independent variables n_i (pronounced n sub i).  Sorry I put the vertical bar in the wrong place. Should be `{ (1^n_i 0 1)^k 1^m | k>=0, n_i >=0, i=1..k, m>=0 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can do it in set-builder notation neatly as follows:

```
L = {w0 w1 w2 … wk | k >= 0, wi in {1, 01}}
```

This doesn't use disjunction, union, intersection or Kleene star explicitly.